# How to pass query parameter as string into jquery load that includes space

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string, multiline

Hi i have a simple question. I want to know how to pass a query string into a query parameter using jquery.

```
function loadPage(queryString) {
    jQuery("#divId").load("myurl/action?param=" + queryString);
}
```

queryString could be like "1,2,3,4" or "testing 1 2 3".

When I tried it only the first parameter is their. I want to be able to pass in a sentence, or a paragraph.

Comment: try using JavaScripts built in `encodeURI(str)`

Comment: I think you want to use encodeURIComponent:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544564/url-encode-a-string-in-jquery-for-an-ajax-request

Comment: Note that encodeURI will keep slashes, and thus if you are trying to pass it in a param, the slashes will break the param.  This is why you should use encodeURIComponent in this case, in other cases where you have a path and want to preserve slashes, then use encodeURI.

Comment: yeah thanks, i needed to keep the "/"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try

```
function loadPage(queryString) {
    jQuery("#divId").load("myurl/action?param=" + encodeURIComponent(queryString));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
function loadPage(queryString) {
    jQuery("#divId").load("myurl/action?param=" + encodeURIComponent(queryString));
}
```