# Can not echo $_GET into JQUERY UI modal dialog

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to echo `$_GET['id']` from URL in `#save_project` which is opened like UI modal. I have tried to fix it, but can not echo yet. This is my jquery script, while clicking I load another php page into `#save_project`

```
 $('#save_project').load('ajax_dialog/save_project.php')
    .dialog({ autoOpen: false, resizable:false, draggable:false, modal:true });

$('#open_save_div').click(
    function () {
        $('#save_project').dialog('open');
        return false;
    }
);

<div id="save_project" title="Projects"></div>
```

**save_project.php**

P.S
When I set `$_GET['id']` to session It works, But I do not want use sessions every time.

Comment: Where exactly do you want your ``$_GET['id']`` variable to appear?

Comment: Have you used isset to be 100% sure that it's actually set?

Comment: Why can you use a global javascript variable and use the same in both places.

Comment: TheOnly92, inside modal box.

Comment: Undefined index: id in .....\ajax_dialog\save_project.php on line 13

Comment: Should the load/filename not have a url / query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_GET means you're going to pull anything that is in the query string of a URL (i.e. anything in a URL after the question mark that takes place after domain).

e.g.

```
http://www.domain.com/?x=123&y=456
```

$_GET would return

```
array ( 'x' => 123 , 'y' => 456 );
```

In the code you have provided, you haven't put a query string anywhere, or indicated where a query string is defined, so it would obviously return an empty string:

`save_project.php` would need to be `save_project.php?q=str&r=blah`

Take a looksee [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757691/how-to-pass-query-parameter-as-string-into-jquery-load-that-includes-space) to see how they put a query string next to their url.