# Posting Text Message Stops at &

Tags: php, jquery

I don't know what is wrong in my code but when I ever I try to post a message with `&` in it on any line or word, it stops on that point and post only the post message text before of that `&`.

For example I'm using this Post Message: `Lorem Ipsum dolor & set imet` If I post this then it posts only this `Lorem Ipsum dolor` and not the whole sentence.

My jQuery is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $("#post_maroozat").on('click', function()
    {
        var message = $( "#maroozat_message" ).val();

        var posthash = $( "#posthash" ).val();
        var lastpid = $( "#lastpid" ).val();
        var tid = $( "#tid" ).val();
        var fid = $( "#fid" ).val();

        if (message == '')
        {
            alert("Message is missing!!");
            return;
        }
        $.ajax(
        {
            type : "post",
            dataType: "html",
            url : "misc.php?action=post_maroozat",
            data : "message="+message+"&posthash="+posthash+"&lastpid="+lastpid+"&tid="+tid+"&fid="+fid,
            success : function(response)
            {
                $('#show_maroozat').html(response);
                $('#maroozat_message').val('');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
if ($mybb->input['action'] == "post_maroozat")
{
    // Set up posthandler.
    require_once MYBB_ROOT."inc/datahandlers/post.php";
    $posthandler = new PostDataHandler("insert");

    // Set the post data that came from the input to the $post array.
    $post = array(
        "tid" => $mybb->input['tid'],
        "fid" => $mybb->input['fid'],
        "uid" => $mybb->user['uid'],
        "username" => $mybb->user['username'],
        "message" => $mybb->input['message'],
        "ipaddress" => get_ip(),
        "posthash" => $mybb->input['posthash']
    );

    $posthandler->set_data($post);

    // Now let the post handler do all the hard work.
    $valid_post = $posthandler->validate_post();

    // Mark thread as read
    require_once MYBB_ROOT."inc/functions_indicators.php";
    mark_thread_read($mybb->input['tid'], $mybb->input['fid']);
    $postinfo = $posthandler->insert_post();

    echo get_latest_post($mybb->input['tid']);
}
```

Please help!

Comment: & is a special character... You need to urlencode it

Comment: Yes, I know, so what's the issue here??

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/q/6544564/1129785

Comment: People should grow-up and NOT to play with down votes all the time :s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
data : "message="+message+"&posthash="+posthash+"&lastpid="+lastpid+"&tid="+tid+"&fid="+fid,
```

to:

```
data : "message="+encodeURIComponent (message)+"&posthash="+posthash+"&lastpid="+lastpid+"&tid="+tid+"&fid="+fid,
```

and you should be all set - the ampersand needs to be properly escaped with `encodeURIComponent`, as it's a special character.

The other option is to pass `data` as an object rather than creating the string yourself.

```
data: { message: message, posthash: posthash, lastpid: lastpid, tid: tid, fid: tid }
```

Comment: It's just a guess, but `data: $('form').serialize()` would probably also do the trick...

Comment: Thanks, it now allows `&` but now it doesn't allow any word having `[ ]` in it. Weird..