# php file_put_contents truncates string after whitespace

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, truncate

file_put_contents seems to truncate my string variable.

HTML

```
<div id="element">
    <?php echo file_get_contents("file.txt"); ?>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function submitData() {
    var string = $('textarea[name=string]').val();
    $('#element').load("submit.php?var="+string);
    $('textarea[name=string]').val("");
    var height = $('#element')[0].scrollHeight;
    $('#element').animate({
        scrollTop: height
    }, 1000);
    $('textarea[name=string]').focus();
}
```

PHP

```
$str = nl2br($_GET['var']);
if(empty($str)) {
    $str = "Error: Empty string.";
}
$str .= "<br /><br />";
$delete = $_GET['delete'];
if(isset($delete)) {
    file_put_contents("file.txt", "");
    echo file_get_contents("file.txt");
} else {
    file_put_contents("file.txt", $str.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    echo file_get_contents("file.txt");
}
```

Result

If the string is "Hello, World!"; I get the following result:

```
Hello,
```

Comment: You will need to URL encode your string if you're passing over GET, eg `load("submit.php?var=" . some_function_to_url_encode(string))`  I don't use jQuery, so I can't speak to the proper method to URL encode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use URL encoded data when sending somthing with a GET request.
see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544564/url-encode-a-string-in-jquery-for-an-ajax-request) for how to do it.