# How to deal with spaces in a PHP request

Tags: php, jquery, spaces

Let's say you have two buttons. Their ids are:

```
bob
bobs burgers
```

You use jquery to .load a php page in a div element like follows:

```
var teamSelect = $(this).attr('id');
$("#loadTables").load("php/leagueTable.php?team="+teamSelect);
```

Now bob will run just fine, but bobs burgers has a space and does not work. The address ends up being

```
"php/leagueTable.php?team=bobs"
```

I have no control over the fact that there will be spaces in the button Ids. The buttons are generated from a database and these names will always have spaces. How can I deal with this?

Comment: encode uricomponent should work.

please refer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544564/url-encode-a-string-in-jquery-for-an-ajax-request][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544564/url-encode-a-string-in-jquery-for-an-ajax-request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to encode the url

```
$("#loadTables").load("php/leagueTable.php?team="+encodeURIComponent(teamSelect));
```

> The encodeURIComponent() method encodes a Uniform Resource Identifier
>   (URI) component by replacing each instance of certain characters by
>   one, two, three, or four escape sequences representing the UTF-8
>   encoding of the character (will only be four escape sequences for
>   characters composed of two "surrogate" characters), [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Comment: Works just like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If these values doesn't contain quotes, then enclose these values with single quotes.

Like:

```
'bob'
'bob burgers'
```

So that when it will passed to the url it will be

```
php/leagueTable.php?team='bob'
php/leagueTable.php?team='bob burgers'
```

Then you can just strip them off afterwards with `trim()`.

Answer (score 0):

As per `w3.org`

```
The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home
subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not 
contain any space characters.
```

You can find more [here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute)