# PHP $_Get and JQuery .load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, get

I want to load another page via Javascript like this

```
$("#resultarea").load("searchresults.php?searchstring=" + $("#searchbox").val());
```

in searchresults.php, a single statement

```
echo $_GET["searchstring"];
```

what I type in searchbox appears when searchresults.php is loaded except when I add space and another word, no thing appear at all. I heared it can be done by encoding or somewhat, I searched but didn't find a solution.

Comment: As you are using jQuery, you can probably do `.load('searchresults.php', {'searchstring': $("#searchbox").val()});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent($("#searchbox").val());
$("#resultarea").load("searchresults.php?searchstring=" + encodedValue);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6544603/2898694)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VD2Q9/9/)