# In php substr(INFORMATICS&SYSTEMS-58600,-5) is returning 'ATICS'

Tags: php, substr

I know this type of questions have been asked before but none solves my problem.

1. I want to capture numeric parts of this string `INFORMATICS&SYSTEMS-58600` i.e. `58600`.
2. I am trying to do `substr(INFORMATICS&SYSTEMS-58600,-5)` which returns `ATICS` which is substr of first part of string `INFORMATICS` but I want the last part.
3. Wherever & is appearing this is behaving same.

I know its a very basic  mistake but what ??? I cant figure out.Please help me out.

Comment: i tried it, it's printing 58600 only.
`echo substr('INFORMATICS&SYSTEMS-58600',-5);` 
what your doing in your code

Comment: Yes you are right the problem is something else. I am trying to pass it as parameter in url i.e.    get_data.php?dept='INFORMATICS&SYSTEMS-58600' through jquery ajax call.

Comment: I have found that i am getting only dept ='informatics'. Which means & is treated as second parameter of url query.

Comment: You need to escape the content in the javascript before passing it down then.

Comment: https://eval.in/446613

Comment: THanks   AlVaz. Now the code is working fine

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'INFORMATICS&SYSTEMS-58600';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Can refer [Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

Actully PHP substr is working fine.
1. I was passing this text as url query in ajax i.e. get_data.php?dept ='informatics& system' so anything after & was treated as second parameter.

2. I found this nice answer on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544564/url-encode-a-string-in-jquery-for-an-ajax-request) to pass ajax parameters in url as encoded.

Answer (score 0):

The regex in this code matches a number at the end of a string.

```
<?php
  $str = "INFORMATICS&SYSTEMS-58600";
  $matches = array();
  preg_match("/\d+$/", $str, $matches);
  foreach($matches as $match) {
    echo $match;
  }
?>
```

Output:

```
58600
```