# Implement Search Functionality Node JS/MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Having some trouble properly implementing a search filter by the Pokemon Name on my Node JS/MySQL DB. When I search I am getting "search/?key=undefined 404 (Not Found)" Any ideas? Here is my search route

```
 router.get('/search', function(req, res){
        var mysql =  req.app.get('mysql');
        var sql='SELECT pokemonname FROM pokemon WHERE pokemonname LIKE "%' + req.key.query + '%';
        sql = mysql.pool.query(sql, function(error, results, fields) {
                if(error) {
                   res.write(JSON.stringify(error));
                   res.end();
                } else {
                        res.status(200);
                        res.end();
        }
   });
});
```

Here is my handlebars file to render the search bar/search button

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <th>Pokemon Name   </th>
        <th>Evolution Level   </th>
        <th>Move Name   </th>
    </thead>
    <input type="text" class="search form-control" id="searchinput" placeholder="Pokemon Name">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" onclick="getUsers({{id}})"/>
        <br>
    <tbody>
        {{#each pokemon}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{pokemonname}}</td>
            <td>{{evolutionlevel}}</td>
            <td>{{movename}}</td>
            <td><button onclick="deletePokemon({{id}})">Delete</td>
        <td><a href="/pokemon/{{id}}">Update</a></td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
```

And finally my search.js function in JQuery

```
function getUsers(searchinput){
        $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/search/?key=' + searchinput,
                success: function(result){
                        window.location.reload(true);
                }
        })
};
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Most occurences of `{{id}}` are used inside `#each` loop suggesting `id` is property of `pokemon` object. Meanwhile your `getUser({{id}})` is used outside of this loop leading to `undefined` passed to binding variable `id`. I think that you want to pass value of text input to your `getUser` function instead, hence your name of formal parameter e.g. `searchinput`. You could use `{{input value=searchinput}}` from [Ember helper](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/classes/Ember.TextField) and then `getUser({{searchinput}})` in your button. Also pay attenttion to [encoding query params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544564/url-encode-a-string-in-jquery-for-an-ajax-request) passed to called AJAX service.