# Http error 400 with % symbol un the url

Tags: php, ajax, http, bad-request

I don't understand exactly why this happend but my proyect in localhost works fine(I'm doing it with laravel). When I do an ajax request like this:

> http://localhost:8000/updateAnalysisPrice/product/Aba%201.525%/todas/0/empty

the server respond with the correct info, the name of the product in this case is  "aba 1.5%"..

Now when I test this in production in godaddy the server returns the error 400 (Bad Request). But if I paste and search the url directly in the browser it returns the values, so the problem is the ajax? or I have to do some extra configuration in the server? I'm doing a GET request in my code.

Comment: You should urlencode that space.

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/q/6544564/689579

Answer (score 0):

@Federkun following you advise I apply the encodeURIComponent to the string "aba 1.5%" in my javascript file and it works fine.. Thank you